# How to express a child or even a grown-up who try to act floppily and sweetly so that you have to give them what they want?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

My children sometimes pull my hand in a floppy way and move around me and ask me sweetly and repeatedly "**Daddy, could you buy me this toy?**" or "**Could you do this for me?**"

Or sometimes my wife just moves floppily in front of me and rubbed my hair playfully and ask me sweetly and repeatedly something like "**Honey, can we have a trip to Hawaii**" or things like that.

In general, they try to be lovely to get me do what they want. They floppily convince me do something for them. Sometimes, I feel annoyed but sometimes I feel that is lovely.

Do we have a word for it in everyday English?

For example, "**My children/wife are being kittenish/childish**"

Comment: Uh, lol, maybe "to sweet-talk" or "to flatter" would be appropriate, depends on whether you want to focus on the flattery or the cute demeanor

Comment: You keep using the word "floppy". That does not mean what you think it means.